# How to share RelativeLayout in item RecyclerView like image in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I have Relativelayout in my items recyclerview,
i want share this item like image when on click button_share == `shareThisScore();`

please anybody help me .

[image]

Xml Item :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            >
        
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutLastScore"
                ..
                    >

                <TextView   .. />
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView ..>
                    <TextView ../>
        
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView ...>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonShare"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"/>
        
            </RelativeLayout>
        
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

onBindViewHolder in my adapter :

```
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScoreViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ScoreItem currentItem = mScoreList.get(position);
    
            holder.mImageViewRank.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageViewRank());
            holder.mTextViewScore.setText(currentItem.getTextViewScore());
            .
            .
            .
    
            holder.mImageButtonShare.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    
                shareThisScore();
            } ); 
    
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem your facing?

Comment: Thank you for react, i'm in level beginner, i want transfer RelativeLayout "relativeLayoutLastScore" to share like image when user click an button share "imageButtonShare" 
note that everything in RecyclerView object

Comment: Ok so you want to implement a system where in your user can share the last score they scored in an image view to their friends or something like that am I right?

Comment: Yes exactly  i want share score like image.

Comment: Well ok if you ask me how to share text I can do it but making it as image am not sure but there is a way so look for something like this

Comment: So the app should automatically take a screenshot and then send that to other applications first look for some tutorial or StackOverflow to take screenshot programmatically and then look for another tutorial where in you can share the taken screenshot to other applications that's all I can say hope you find answer

Comment: as you said, yes i can share item like text but not like image. note that I can share an object as image, if the object outside recyclerview.